# Not getting the paymentId in webhookUrl or redirectUrl in mollie payment integration with node

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, mollie

```
 const customerPayment = await mollieClient.customerPayments.create({
    customerId: "cst_vK6rVTW5gr",
    amount: {
      value: process.env.STANDARD_ACCOUNT_CHARGE,
      currency: "EUR",
    },
    description: "Payment",
    redirectUrl:
      "https://1137-43-251-72-102.ngrok-free.app/payment/redirect",
    webhookUrl:
      "https://1137-43-251-72-102.ngrok-free.app/payment/webhook",

    locale: "nl_NL",
  });


//apis

paymentRoute.get("/redirect", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body.id;

  console.log("redirect id :>> ", id);
  console.log("req.headers :>> ", req.headers);
  const paymentId = req.query.id; 
 
  console.log("payment id:>> ", paymentId); //undefined
});
```

I have tried many solution like api method change  post and get ,
from query and body and params but still not getting.

Is there anyone have solution ?